# How To Parse JSON DATA IN ORACLE

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

A table has JSON data in the HUGECLOB column. And I want to parse it. How can I do it?

```
{"errors":{"destination_country_id":["can not be blank"],"dispatch_country_id":["can not be blank"],"vehicle_id":["can not be blank"],"trailer_id":["can not be blank"]}}
```

I tried this;

```
  SELECT t.*
    FROM table,
         JSON_TABLE(_hugeclob_data, '$'
              COLUMNS (destination_country_id  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.destination_country_id',
                       dispatch_country_id     VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.dispatch_country_id',
                       vehicle_id              VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.vehicle_id',
                       trailer_id              VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.trailer_id'                  
                      )
                  ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are scalars but defined as arrays (like in your sample), do it like this

```
SELECT t.*
    FROM table t1,
         JSON_TABLE(_hugeclob_data format json, '$.errors'
              COLUMNS (destination_country_id  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.destination_country_id[*]',
                       dispatch_country_id     VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.dispatch_country_id[*]',
                       vehicle_id              VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.vehicle_id[*]',
                       trailer_id              VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$.trailer_id[*]'                  
                      )
                  ) t;
```

But if they are actually arrays, you'll need to use 'nested path' declaration to unwind the arrays

Comment: Thank your reply, but when  i tried to run this, i get this error;

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option. It takes the first element of the each of the arrays:

```
create table test_table (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint test_table_id_pk primary key,
    clob_data                      clob  CHECK (clob_data IS JSON)
)
;

INSERT INTO test_table(clob_data) VALUES
(
'{
  "errors": {
    "destination_country_id": [
      "can not be blank"
    ],
    "dispatch_country_id": [
      "can not be blank"
    ],
    "vehicle_id": [
      "can not be blank"
    ],
    "trailer_id": [
      "can not be blank"
    ]
  }
}');

SELECT t.*
FROM test_table,
JSON_TABLE(clob_data, '$.errors'
COLUMNS (row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
         destination_country_id VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.destination_country_id[0]',
         dispatch_country_id VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.dispatch_country_id[0]',
         vehicle_id VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.vehicle_id[0]',
         trailer_id VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.trailer_id[0]'
        ))
AS t;

ROW_NUMBER DESTINATION_COUNTRY_ DISPATCH_COUNTRY_ID  VEHICLE_ID           TRAILER_ID          
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 can not be blank     can not be blank     can not be blank     can not be blank
```

Comment: Thank your reply, but when i tried to run this, i get this error;

Comment: That is an issue with how you run those statements in Toad. I created a working example that consist of 3 statements (create table, insert row, select from table). I'm not familiar with Toad.